# Windows 10 update leads to grub rescue

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, grub2, windows-10, grubrescue

Windows 10 recently ran updates on my system and suddenly it lead to grub rescue. I have a dual-boot system with Ubuntu 16.04 installed.

When I do `ls` on the grub rescue prompt, I get the following:

```
(hd0)   (hd0,msdos5)   (hd0,msdos3)   (hd0,msdos2)   (hd0,msdos1)
```

Doing `ls` on each of the partitions gives me an unknown filesystem error.

When I do `set`, I get

```
cmdpath=(hd0)
prefix=(hd0,msdos6)/boot/grub
root=hd0,msdos6
```

How do I restore grub and get back both Ubuntu 16.04 and windows 10? I have some important data on my Ubuntu system (without backup, sadly).

UPDATE 1:
Installed testdisk successfully. Following is the output of the analyze command:

[Testdisk analyze output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8dWq8.png)

How do I proceed to correctly set the grub path and restore/recover my Ubuntu partition ? Please reply.

UPDATE 2: Following is the output of the deep scan:

[Deep Scan output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xAcpc.png)

It says that 3 partitions (all Linux and having the same size) can't be recovered. I stumbled upon this link where the asker faced the same problem:
[Grub rescue after "Windows Anniversary Update"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/834618/grub-rescue-after-windows-anniversary-update?rq=1)

Can I directly do what he has said:
"After it (deep scan) was done I labeled the Windows launcher to *. (Primary bootable) I then named the rest P. (Primary) I opened grub rescue again, after saving the partition table, and ran ls."

Let me know. This issue is getting serious.

Comment: Please see my answer to this exact question at https://askubuntu.com/questions/957117/windows-10-major-update-wiped-grub-how-do-i-recover-partitions-properly/957142#957142

Comment: @heynnema I have updated the question with details of testdisk output. Please reply how to proceed.

Comment: Your Ubuntu partition was probably between partitions 4 & 5, probably starting at 12748/118/41, ending at 60294/81/11, or there-abouts. You'll have to follow the help file that I point out in my other answer.

Comment: UPDATE 3: This is the current output of the analyze on testdisk:Testdisk analyze output after running deep scan - https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qu9je.png


I see that this output is different from the output in UPDATE 1. Is there any information that can be used to recover my Linux partition ?

Comment: This is the updated testdisk result:

https://i.imgur.com/xzM8CGA.png

This output is different from the output in UPDATE 1. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I notice you are missing (hd0,msdos4) and (hd0,msdos6). Were these your Ubuntu partitions?
There has been issue with win10 doing a major update and deleting linux partitions.

Boot from a LiveCD and select try ubuntu. If testdisk isn't installed, open a terminal and type
`sudo apt-get install testdisk` then `sudo testdisk`

scan for deleted partitions and add the ones that fit the holes between your partitions.

In most cases that is enough to get it to boot.

Comment: I don't know which were Ubuntu partitions. How can I find out ? Also, could you detail the steps to use testdisk. How can I find it ?

Comment: @mahesh -- answer updated

Comment: can you please guide me ? I have updated my question with further outputs. I am stuck on this since too long.

Comment: @Mahesh --  add the two linux partitions and reboot

Comment: What will then happen to Windows OS ? Will I be able to access it still ?

I am assuming you want me to add the two linux partitions shown in this image:
https://i.imgur.com/xzM8CGA.png

How do I do that ? Should I do that by selecting "Write" option at the bottom of the screen ?

Sorry for such questions, but I want to be sure before taking any step.

Comment: yes write them, it won't do anything to windows

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qu9je.png

In this image, the NTFS partitions are marked with D (delete), so I am worried. What do the D's indicate here ?

Comment: those are old deleted partitions, you can not restore those because they will over write the new ones made by the update, just restore the two linux partitions

Comment: Thanks for the help. It solved my problem. However, whenever I shut down my system, it is again showing the grub rescue menu. How do I make the fix permanent ?

Comment: if you can get booted into your install. then update grub and initramfs.

Comment: I just did "sudo update-grub". Then shutdown and restarted. Same problem again.

You mean, I have to boot using LiveCD ?

Comment: try this https://askubuntu.com/a/931327/694267. replace `(hd0,1)` with `(hd0,6)` and `/sda1` with `/sda6`